# Technology island

Tags: riddle, word

Here is a very easy riddle for you:

> I am a piece of land but I am also technology.
>   I am drowning and many people think that my time is over.
>   But still, many people build on me.
>   Some people want to relocate a part of me to somewhere else.

Who am I?

Hint 1

> Anything in this riddle relates to both sides of me.

Hint 2

> If you really have no idea of who I am, you may look a little bit closer at this Stack Exchange Account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> Java

---

I am a piece of land but I am also technology.

> [The island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java) and the [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))

I am drowning and many people think that my time is over.

> The sea level is rising slowly over the island (25cm a year in Jakarta), and java can be considered an older coding language as it was released in 1995, and there's lots of new languages out there now

But still, many people build on me.

> Build on the island and build with the code

Some people want to relocate a part of me to somewhere else.

> Jakarta, the capital of Indonesia, is quickly sinking and [there are plans of moving it](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/aug/26/indonesia-new-capital-city-borneo-forests-jakarta) to Borneo, and programmers can move language, for instance from java to C#

Also, a line from the OP's bio:

> "Programming languages that I like: java, java and (most importantly) JAVA"

Comment: About the part of the relocation of the technology: There are even 2 possibilities (I can think of) but both possibilities require a bit of knowledge.

Comment: @dan1st I've come up with moving sprites and moving files, either of those?

Comment: No, it's something of the language...or maybe the community, you may find one thing if you really look at the hints...but this is clearly the most difficult part :)

Comment: @dan1st perhaps [this](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/)? I'll be honest I've looked loads and can't find anything that fits perfectly

Comment: Actually, I have not thought about that but it is kind of close.

Comment: @dan1st could it just be changing programming language? Other than that I am stumped

Comment: @dan1st is there a reference to Java runtime environment becoming non-free in that 'thnink time is over' - alternatively maybe because python is now more popular than java...

Comment: Changing the programming language (mainly to C# as it is the same but with a few small changes) is indeed one of the options I considered for this answer :)